# Efficiently determine if a List is using item level security

Tags: development, permissions, performance, object-model

How can you efficiently determine if any of the items in a List **don't** inherit their security from the List?

You could use [SPListItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.hasuniqueroleassignments.aspx) but this would require iterating through all items in the List.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leading on from @tylerrrr07's answer, there's another overload of `GetItemsWithUniquePermissions` which may be of use to you:

[MSDN: SPList.GetItemsWithUniquePermissions Method (int maxItemToReturn, bool folderOnly)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee576271.aspx)

You could then avoid the potentially huge result set from running the method by using the following:

```
SPList.GetItemsWithUniquePermissions(1, false).Count == 1
```

Comment: If this actually bypasses the SPQueryThrottledException issue (which I imagine it should) its a great solution. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @tylerrrr07: Thanks. The exception description seems to indicate that it's triggered by the size of its own result set; but of course that's no guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested it myselt but it looks like you could do something along the lines of

```
SPList.GetItemsWithUniquePermissions().Count > 0;
```

Comment: A minor problem with this solution is that all the list items have with item-level permissions are returned by the function (which may be all of them). This in turn may cause it to throw an SPQueryThrottledException: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee572463.aspx